# A doubt on the terminology on joint probability distributions and marginal distributions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose that $(\Omega_i,\mathcal{F}_i,\mu_i)$, $i=1,2$ be two probability measure spaces. Consider the product measure space $(\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2, \mathcal{F}_1\otimes \mathcal{F}_2)$. I couldnt understand the statement a ``joint distribution on $(\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2, \mathcal{F}_1\otimes \mathcal{F}_2)$ with marginal distributions $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$''. I know that if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two random variables on a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mu)$. Then the map $\textbf{f}: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $x \mapsto (X_1(x),X_2(x))$ is a Borel function from $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^2$.Then $\mu\circ \textbf{f}^{-1}$ is called the joint distribution with marginal distributions $\mu_1 \circ X_1^{-1}$ and $\mu_2 \circ X_2^{-1}$. What if the random variables are on different measure spaces. Is the joint distribution is $\mu_1 \times \mu_2\circ \textbf{X}^{-1}$ where $\textbf{X}: X_1\times X_2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ mapping $(x_1,x_2) \mapsto (X_1(x_1),X_2(x_2))$?

Comment: Joint distributions, independence etc are defined only for r.v.'s defined on the same space.

Comment: what does this statement ``joint distribution on $(\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2, \mathcal{F}_1\otimes \mathcal{F}_2)$ with marginal distributions μ1 and μ2'' mean?

Comment: It is a measure $P$ on the product such that $P(A\times \Omega_2)=\mu_1(A)$ and $P(\Omega_1 \times B)=\mu_2(B)$.